# Numbering of <ol> items NOT using <li> value property

Tags: html, jquery-ui

I have a (jquery ui) sortable list with li-elements, that hold information (an id for further processing) in their value-attribute.

However, I want my list to show numbering next to it, similar to this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/knj92mvu/

(Of course I mean the numbering of #correctList, to be sure ...)

```
$("#myOL").sortable({
update: function (event, ui) {
    console.log('new index of dropped item:' + ui.item.index());
                }
});
```

Now the OL elements think theyre smart by getting their position number from the value-property of the li. But, as said, the value-property is important for me and I can not overwrite it.

Is there a way I can display correct numbering of the items (1, 2, 3 for my example link given above) ignoring the value-property?

---

A possible workaround I can imagine: use one of the events of the .sortable(), get the index of the items and write it to the innerText of the li.

However I want to ensure there is no "clean" workaround for this, where I can assign certain numbering to lists, ignoring the value-property. Basically also for information how I could solve this WITHOUT jquery ui.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [CSS Counters](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_gen_counter-increment.asp)

**CSS:**

```
#myOL{
    list-style-position: inside;
    list-style-type: none;
}

#myOL ol{
    counter-reset: list 1;
}

#myOL li:before {
    content: counter(list) '. ';
}

#myOL li{
    padding: 4px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    counter-increment: list 1;
}
```

[JSFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/knj92mvu/1/)

Answer (score 1):

You can circumvent the counting logic entirely by using `<div>`s instead of `<li>`s:

```
<ol>
<div style="display:list-item;" value="whatever">Text</div>
<ol>
```

Here's your fiddle updated: http://jsfiddle.net/mbw41oj5/

Comment: Thank you for you effort, however I like the solution given by Tobías better since I don't have to change any markup. As I already have some logic hooked up with my li-elements, changing this to DIVs would be possible but required more work.

Comment: @konrad_pe Yes, the other answer is probably better-- it *overrides* the logic, I just thought I'd offer the alternative of going *around* rather than *through* it